does *x = *x + 1 add 1 to the value of x or to the address of x?
I was studying about bubble sort and I came by this expression. It seems like the equation adds 1 to the address of x but the video said it adds one to the value of x. Can someone please explain and confirm which one is the right explanation?
I didn't try out anything.

changing the address: x = <something>;; changing the contents: *x = <something>;

Assuming x is an address, *x will be the thing that x is the address of.  Does that help?

Neither. It adds 1 to the value that x points to.

What does * do, according to your understanding?

The * prepended to a pointer (pointer=variable holding the address of its object) dereferences the pointer, meaning that the result of this expression (yes in C also *x is an expression) is the value pointed by the pointer.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

This is a tutorial-level question about very basic C functionality.  I suggest first learning the language, then posting questions about less obvious things, rather than things you could learn from most tutorials.

I’m voting to close this question because it is too basic. OP should not ask questions before learning the very basic things.

@0___________ we are all here to learn, if we can't ask questions we want answers to then the concept of this whole site does not make sense, I just like to ask questions when I don't understand something completely, I'm not asking you for the answer in particular so you can just go and answer some other question instead of trying to act all high and mighty in this comment section.

The question isn't off-topic here. But as noticed, very basic questions that are easiest answered by reading a C book aren't usually well-received. If the book is any good, it will also explain things in a more pedagogic way than the average C answer on SO will. Many people who write answers here might implicitly assume that you already know the basics.

See C operator precedence table.
So, expression
*x = *x + 1;

is same as
(*x) = ((*x) + 1);

and *x means the value, more accurately lvalue, ie. value which can be on the left side of assignment, at the address where pointer x points to.
So, it takes the value from *x, adds 1 to the value, then assigns it back to *x.
It's same as *x += 1;

Re "It's same as *x += 1;", (*x)++; , ++*x;

thanks for the comment it helped me understand where I was going wrong

I have a follow up question though. Does it mean that on the left hand side of the assignment operator *x points to the location of the variable that is stored in x but on the right hand side it operates on the value?

@user19978719 Yes, that is correct. There are even some formal strange terms that you may encounter in compiler messages called lvalue or rvalue. The name of them literally comes from "left/right operand of assignment". A lvalue in C is something that has a memory location and can be modified (like *x), whereas a rvalue is something which doesn't have an addressable memory location (like the integer constant  1). So if we write nonsense code like 1 = 2; the compiler will say something strange like "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".
